# PHP CodeIgniter 4 - Form Submission - error "Can't find a route for 'registrations/index'"

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, form-submit, codeigniter-4

I'm using the `form_open()` helper method within the view to indicate the controller method to handle the form submission action and have the route defined in `app\Config\Routes.php`.

I'm still getting an error `Can't find a route for 'registrations/index'`.

Please assist with the issue. The code snippets are provided below.

##### Error:

[image]

##### `register.php` view file:

```
            <?php echo form_open('/registrations/index'); ?>
```

##### `Registrations.php` controller:

```
class Registrations extends BaseController {

    public function index() {

        $data['coursename'] = $this->getCourseName();  

        log_message('info','name field >' . $this->request->getVar('iname') . '<<');

        echo view('templates/header');
        echo view('pages/register', $data);
        echo view('templates/footer');
    }
```

Routes.php

```
$routes->get('/registrations/index', 'Registrations::index');
```

Answer (score 9):

I think your AutoRoutes is set to false by default.

add this line in your `Routes.php`

```
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
```

Comment: there is a comment in Routes.php that mentioned `The Auto Routing (Legacy) is very dangerous`. If you want to enable it, don't forget to set `$autoRoutesImproved = true;` in app/Feature.php . Not sure why is the improved one not set to `true` by default

Answer (score 6):

```php
form_open('/registrations/index')
```

##### Explanation:

The above line of code would create a form that points to your site URL plus the “/registrations/index” URI segments, like this:

```html
<form action="http://your-site-domain.com/index.php/registrations/index" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

If you look hard enough at the auto-generated opening `form` tag above, this will essentially make a `POST` HTTP request. Yet you defined your route in the `app\Config\Routes.php` file using a `->get(...)` method.

##### Solution:

Instead of (`Routes.php`):❌

```php
$routes->get('/registrations/index', 'Registrations::index');
```

Use this: ✅

```php
$routes->post('/registrations/index', 'Registrations::index');
```

---

*Notice the use of `->post(...)`.*

Resource: [Form Helper](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, the controller works now